# Why don't the Oberon's ruins resemble the space station?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes

In the 2001 *Planet of The Apes*, at the beginning of the movie, the Oberon space station looks huge. Thousands of years after its crash, its wreckage does not resemble the original space station. The ruin is really small, compared to the size of the space station.

**What happened to the rest? I tried to compare the wreckage with the original spaceship. Is the wreckage the very upper part of the space station ?**

Comment: The control room seen in the buried version is NOT the same control room seen at the beginning. The primary control room seen at the beginning is some distance from the animal cages, whereas the smaller control room seen in the buried version is right around the corner from them.

Answer (score 2):

The two most plausible reasons are

**A) Most of it is buried under the sand.** It's been a long time since it crashed to earth, so enough time has passed that a large portion of it is buried

**B) It broke up / burned up on re-entry** Only part of the original station made it through the atmosphere

Comment: Probably a bit of both. Plus, as the OP speculates, only the upper part of the station is visible and/or present.

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at the portion of the ship that is not buried. The spikes and spires are at the very lowermost portion of the ship. The engine cones were located there I presume. Also, I believe the presumption is the control room was located very close to the entrance to the wrecked hull. I do not believe that to be the case. I believe the ship broke up during the crash and the lower portion is protruding from the ground.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  If you've noticed a correspondence between the pre-crash station and the remnant seen on the ground it would be really helpful if you could post pictures.  Despite what you might hear elsewhere, hand-drawn red circles are actually optional. ;)

Comment: @DavidW They are?! :)